# res send 2 html files in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm devloping a sample website in order the learn Node.js with express. In a routes file I have this code to render a page:

```
app.get('/new-product', requireLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/../views/new-product.html'));
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```

Is there a way I could have the page header (with the logo, menus, etc) in a separated html file so I can load the header in all pages from the same file, and the content of each page in another file?

Comment: You should take a look at [templating](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html). Most templating languages have an option to include common parts of a page from other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to load a piece of page in all pages , you need to use the **EJS** engine in place of html , just use `<% include name_of_the_view %>` in your ejs page and each time this page 'll be rendered , the *name_of_the_view* will be rendered with it 
learn more : 
http://www.embeddedjs.com/